# Scala 2.12.15 giving build issues

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, maven-scala-plugin

I am using Spark Scala. I am trying to upgrade scala to 2.12.15 and during build getting below issue.

```
scala.tools.nsc.Settings.nowarn()Lscala/tools/nsc/settings/AbsSettings$AbsSetting;
xsbt.Command$.getNoWarn(Command.scala:36)
xsbt.DelegatingReporter$.apply(DelegatingReporter.scala:19)
xsbt.CachedCompiler0.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:75)
xsbt.CompilerInterface.newCompiler(CompilerInterface.scala:22)
```

What could be done?

Comment: Did you try to upgrade sbt?

Comment: I am using maven.

Comment: Please attach `pom.xml`.

Comment: Connected discussion: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/scala-compilation-issue-in-2-12-15/8792

Comment: You have seem to have omitted the actual name of the error. Is it a `NoSuchMethodError`, or what?